# In dreamweaver why i am seeing php boxes instead of original php like in browser

Tags: php

I have setup the site with new site option in Dreamweaver.
I have stored php file in htdocs of xampp folder.
then I opened the file in Dreamweaver in split view and here is what i get.[image]

on the right hand site i get two php boxes instead of "Hello World!"

but when i click on the boxes, i get some property like this,
[image]

but when i run the file in my browser it correctly shows "Hello World"
Why is this happening?

when i click on discover i get Script warning like this
[image]

after clicking yes i get message like "An unknown error occurred while discovering dynamically-related files - Retry."

Comment: What heppens whwn you click on link Discover?

Comment: I get Script warning

Comment: after clicking yes i get message like "An unknown error occurred while discovering dynamically-related files - Retry."

Comment: It means that it not simple like you and me think http://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/dreamweaver/articles/setup_php.html

Answer (score 0):

It means that Dreamweaver is only editor, not browser. In browser you must write URL like localhost etc, and Dreamweaver must have option Open in browser, if not, you must manualy.

Comment: I have seen php online tutorial where in Dreamweaver split view you get browser like experience. So why it is not happening in my case.